# Datetime picker doesn't popup when dynamically generated from Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-datetimepicker

I am facing problem with [Bootstrap Datetime picker](https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/).

**Issue :** When I try to add static code in HTML, it just works fine. The popup(date-time picker) comes up, and even the functionality is fine. But, when I try to generate the same HTML using Javascript, it fails to work. Only the input text box appears. But, the popup doesn't come up. What am I doing wrong?

**Here is my static HTML code(this works)-**

```
<div class="col-sm-9">
<input size="16" type="text" value="2016-04-15 14:45" readonly class="form_datetime">
</div>
```

**I needed the same HTML to be dynamically generated from Javascript(this doesn't work)-**

```
tableStr += '<td>\
<input size="16" type="text" value="2016-04-15 10:00" readonly class="form_datetime" id="dealstarttime'+i+'">\
</td>\
<td>\
<input size="16" type="text" value="2016-05-15 10:00" readonly class="form_datetime" id="dealendtime'+i+'">\
</td>';
```

**I have this code in the onload()-**

```
$(".form_datetime").datetimepicker({format: 'yyyy-mm-dd hh:ii'});
```

Comment: you have to reinitialize the datetimepicker after appending html in the dom.

Comment: I know this is not the answer to the question but may I suggest using `<input type="datetime-local">` and you are good to go?

Comment: @KartikeyaKhosla You mean I have to do `$(".form_datetime").datetimepicker({format: 'yyyy-mm-dd hh:ii'});` after at the end of `tableStr`? I am using a loop to fill the table with say 10 such datetime pickers. So, I need to put this code inside the loop right?

Comment: @bozzmob..No just reinitialize datetimepicker after the loop once all html appended.

Comment: @KartikeyaKhosla Thanks a lot. I did it and it worked :)

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by Kartikeya in the comments,

I reinitialized the datetime picker by having this line of code at the end of my loop that was generating the HTML dynamically.

My code now looked like this-

```
function generatePickers() {
    for (var i = 0; i < deals.length; i++) {

        tableStr += '<td>\
            <input size="16" type="text" value="2016-04-15 10:00" readonly class="form_datetime" id="dealstarttime' + i + '">\
            </td>\
            <td>\
            <input size="16" type="text" value="2016-05-15 10:00" readonly class="form_datetime" id="dealendtime' + i + '">\
            </td>';

    }

    //I ADDED THIS PIECE OF CODE, and now it WORKS!
    $(".form_datetime").datetimepicker({
        format: 'yyyy-mm-dd hh:ii'
    });
}
```